# How to a parameterize a triangle oriented counter clockwise?

Tags: calculus, parametrization, line-integrals

I am trying to calculate a line integral around a triangle that is oriented counter-clockwise.

The triangle is bounded by:
$$y=0$$
$$x=3$$
$$y=x$$

I know how to parameterize the y=0 and x=3 parts of the triangle but I am unsure how to parameterize the y=x part as it is oriented counter clockwise.

For $c_1$ and $c_2$ I get $$\vec{r_1}=<t,0>$$ and $$\vec{r_2}=<3,t>$$

How can I get $\vec{r_3}$?

Answer (score 1):

Given two points $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$, a simple parameterization of the line segment joining them is $\mathbf r(t) = (1-t)\mathbf p+t\mathbf q$. You can see that $\mathbf r(0)=\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf r(1)=\mathbf q$. Choose the start and end points of your line segment accordingly to get the correct orientation for it.

Comment: So <3-t,3-t> would be a parameterization for $\vec{r_3}$?

Comment: @Fernando With $0\le t\le3$, yes.